# SQL Class for all operations with database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, class, reference

I want to write a class for all interactions with the database and have some problemes.

```
class Sqlconnection
{
    private string connection = null;

    private string result = null;

    public SqlConnection dbConnection() 
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionInfo"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I cant reference to the class with this.connection. I want to use the connection in some other functions like connectionCmd and connectionClose. How can I reference the sql connection string to the class? And the return false will not work, but this is necessary to check in the mainprogram, if the connection buildup was successful?

Thank you all!

Comment: What *value* is this class adding for you? The `SqlConnection` object that you're already working with has `Open`, `Close` and `ExecuteXXX` methods defined on it.

Comment: To expand on @Damien_The_Unbeliever's point - if the purpose of your class is to add utility helper functions, then "extension methods" are a good way of doing that. Now... if only libraries that did that already existed (cough "dapper" cough)

Comment: You can't return with bool when the method's return value is an SqlConnection reference. It is not even can be compiled.

Comment: I want to use this class in my mainprogram for all sql interactions. So I want a greate a new object with ... sqlconnection = new SqlConnection and call the public function to check, if the connection build up was successful. Like conn = sqlConnection.dbConnection(); and if (conn)...

Comment: Btw, calling it `Sqlconnection` is just *asking* for confusion - especially when it wraps `SqlConnection`. I understand that you want to do that, but it isn't clear to me *why* you want to do that, i.e. what value it is going to be adding...

Comment: @mnlfischer Than you can return with null instead of false... And check if the conn is not null. conn = sqlConnection.dbConnection(); and if (conn != null).

Comment: @MarcGravell In my mainprogramm, I have lots of sql calls and I dont want to create in every function an sql object with all of the stuff to create it. I think it is comfortable to have a class and I only need to call some function of the class to interact with the database.

Comment: All you have shown so far is a dubious implementation of a single factory method. If what you want is a factory method, then fix the return type and you're pretty much sorted. But I still don't know what value `Sqlconnection` is adding here *other* than exposing a single factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is your dreadful choice of name for your class. It is far too easy to confuse `Sqlconnection` and `SqlConnection`. I misread your code twice due to that. So give your class a proper name for starters. Next, decide whether you want to encapsulate the `SqlConenction` or not. There is little point in writing a class to handle all interactions with the database if it gives the rest of your application access to the connection.

You are probably after doing something like:

```
class DatabaseAccessLayer
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public DatabaseAccessLayer(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public bool CreateDbConnection() 
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Add other methods to interact with the database
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to access a private member of a private class from a different class? if I am reading you correct you need to look at access modifiers and what private, public, static and internal (and others) mean. if I am not reading you correctly I apologise and please ignore my comment or tell me to put on some glasses.

Comment: the private string connection is private because only the SqlConnection class need it. I want to create a new object of the class in my mainprogramm and call the public function dbConnection to create a connection. Is this not the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get your self improved on OO Coding. and if you want to have a central class for all SQL task, why re inventing the wheel. why dont you try this :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=435

Comment: Suggesting someone avoid re-inventing the wheel by pointing them to an article that re-invents the wheel is't very helpful.

Comment: @DavidArno sorry i wanted to give the Data access application block not the above :S.